# Cannot figure out why I cannot deploy GWT application onto Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: gwt, tomcat, tomcat7, gwt-rpc

First, I tried to follow the tutorial to deploy my application. After some fiddling and failures, I thought I should run the GWT sample Contacts project and see if that will work on my tomcat with RPC calls. Again, no luck. What I did was create a sample application (when using Eclipse Wizard) compile, run it once on the development server, and see that it works.

Then I take the contents of the war folder, zip it, rename it to SampleApp.war, deploy it on the Apache, it unzips. I have a folder called SampleApp. In it is the .html, .css, WEB-INF. I attempt to do localhost:8080/SampleApp/SampleApp.html but it doesnt work.

> type Status report
>
> message /SampleApp/SampleApp.html
>
> description The requested resource (/SampleApp/SampleApp.html) is not
>   available.

I have no idea what to do. I tried to do the simple example possible and get it to work but I cannot. Help!

UPDATED: [Cannot deploy servlet sample GWT app to Apache Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096617/cannot-deploy-servlet-sample-gwt-app-to-apache-tomcat-7)

Comment: What is the folder you get after tomcat explodes your handwrapped war file? What are its content? It would help if you share your webapps folder structure and log file in your tomcat logs directory.

Comment: i will do so tomorrow. ill edit my post

Comment: You are renaming the folder, but not the html file. So access the correct html file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot deploy servlet sample GWT app to Apache Tomcat 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096617/cannot-deploy-servlet-sample-gwt-app-to-apache-tomcat-7)

Answer (score 0):

To Deploy a gwt app on tomcat you have to create war file using ANT.

Follow this link to create the war file and then put that war file in webapps folder of tomcat it will surely work.

http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/